# Convert Core DNN Forum's to YAF.NET for DNN or ActiveForums

Tags: forum, dotnetnuke

Does anyone know of a way to convert all the forums, posts, etc. from the core DNN Forum module to the [YAF.NET DNN module](http://dnnyafnet.codeplex.com/) or [Active Forums](http://www.activemodules.com/)? I've searched for hours and can't find anything about how to do this other then people saying there's not a scrip to do it yet. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If you haven't heard, the core forum is being retired and replaced with Active Forums.  So, they're actively working on an official upgrade script.  I believe they've said it'll be delivered with DNN 6 in Q2 2011...

Comment: I heard about that but was hoping someone would have an upgrade script they used, or the trial version of 3.7 of Active Forums so I can use the script that's on there website.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Active Forums has come a long way in the past few months.  It has gained some much needed support in the open source world on Codeplex.

There is an upgrade script that I've personally used to migrate forum content from DNN Forum to Active Forums.  There is even Tapatalk support for mobile devices.

Feel free to check it out at [activeforums.codeplex.com](http://activeforums.codeplex.com) or the [activeforums.org](http://activeforums.org) website.